# How to combine 2 Postgres queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT orders.customer
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN uploads
ON uploads.order = orders.id
WHERE uploads.order IS NULL
AND orders.product_type = 'warrior_workout'


INSERT INTO uploads ( id, order, name, url, file_name, is_main ) VALUES
  (DEFAULT, orders.customer, "warrior_workout_nonhomeworkout","https://example.org","6 Week Warrior Workout Non-Home Workout.pdf",true),
  (DEFAULT, orders.customer, "warrior_workout_homeworkout","https://example.org","6 Week Warrior Workout Home Workout.pdf",true),
  (DEFAULT, orders.customer, "men_six_week_summer_shredder","https://example.org","Men's Six Week Summer Shredder.pdf",true);
```

I have 2 postgres queries, and I need to combine them into one.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You're showing us two queries, but one is an straightforward insert, the other is a select -- you probably don't want to combine those two. Can you show us what queries you have, what you've tried, and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: This is it. I want to do 3 INSERT per record returned by the first query.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my example. One of the rows to populate is named "order". I made an edit, but it just made it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
INSERT INTO uploads (customer, name, url, file_name, is_main ) 
    SELECT o.customer, v.*
    FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
         uploads u
         ON u.order = o.id CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES ('warrior_workout_nonhomeworkout', 'https://example.org', '6 Week Warrior Workout Non-Home Workout.pdf', true),
                 ('warrior_workout_homeworkout', 'https://example.org', '6 Week Warrior Workout Home Workout.pdf', true),
                 ('men_six_week_summer_shredder', 'https://example.org', 'Men''s Six Week Summer Shredder.pdf', true)
         ) v(name, url, file_name, is_main)
    WHERE u.order IS NULL AND o.product_type = 'warrior_workout';
```

For each of the customers missing the upload, this inserts those three values.

Comment: Gordon is using the `VALUES` statement to create a fake table called `v`. `v.*` just means "all the columns in `v`".